# CSS/JS - Disable click events but allow scrolling on DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Pretty much title, I would like to allow scrolling in a DIV, but disable click events. Does anyone know any way this could be accomplished?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `$('div_selector').off('click')`

Comment: `.myDiv { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me create a special class that prevents click events then wrap these element(s) with a scrollable container.

```
<div class="scrollable-div">
    <div class="child-div noclick">
    //anything else
    </div>
 </div>
```

and your js would look like

```
$('.noclick').click(function(event){
    // prevent default behavior of click
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDiv = document.querySelector('#myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){

    return false
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some reason... https://jsfiddle.net/rohanssrao/t0y4w2mo/